Single Sign On (SSO) in Configuration tab of Microsoft Teams Toolkit
I have successfully implemented SSO for personal tab. but while requesting the same from configuration tab in chats it throws the error:
App webApplicationInfo or resource not defined in manifest
I can get the client side token using microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken(authTokenRequest); from the Personal tab but when runs same in configuration tab in chats it above throws error
my webApplicationInfo json looks like this
